# Create a new browser session using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor MVC project which is a web form. Users are allowed to enter data on the form (asked via a series of questions). The data entered by the user is stored in a C# Session variable `Session["somedata"]`.

I want the session variable to lose its contents when the page re-loads (which I haven't seen happening). So, I made a "Start Over" button on the form which on click should destroy the current contents of the `Session["somedata"]`. Is there a way I can forcefully fire a new session from the view? (or the controller?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to explicitly killing someData?

```
    if (Session["someData"] != null)
        Session.Remove("someData");
```